# FileInputStream("hello.txt"), doesn't work unless I specify an absolute path (C:\User\Documents etc)

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Hi is there any way I can get FileInputStream to read `hello.txt` in the same directory without specifying a path?

```
package hello/
    helloreader.java
    hello.txt
```

My error message: `Error: .\hello.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Comment: In the same directory _of what?_

Comment: It should work, if the file is in the current working directory.

Comment: "doesn't work", do you get any Exceptions ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way :) Just make sure that the `hello.txt` file is at the same level as your jar file if you have any or your project if you are still developing (not the same as your encapsuling class then).

Comment: I"m using eclipse and the .txt file is in the same package as the .java file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read file with relative path like.

```
File file = new File("./hello.txt");
```

- YourProject

  ->bin

  ->hello.txt

  ->.classpath

  ->.project

Here is works

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class fileInputStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("./hello.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            System.out.println("Total file size to read (in bytes) : "
                    + fis.available());

            int content;
            while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
                // convert to char and display it
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fis != null)
                    fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("Filename.txt")`, but your text file has to be in the same directory/package as your `YourClassName` file.

Comment: Thanks. Does this only happen for certain IDEs? I've tried good old text editor and command line and it works fine.

Comment: This won't work if you are going to deploy a web project as a .war file that puts your Java classes in the WEB-INF/classes folder, which many commonly do now.

Answer (score 4):

When you open "hello.txt" you are opening a file in the current [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the process. i.e. where the program was run from, not where your jar is or some other directory.

Answer (score 3):

When you open your file with path `hello.txt`, the file `hello.txt` should be in the same directory of where you execute the `java` command, that is the working directory. And you can use the following code to print the working directory when you run a Java program:

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Suppose you execute your code like this `java hello.helloreader`, then you should use the following path to get the `hello.txt`:

```java
new FileInputStream("hello/hello.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try System.getProperty("dir") to show your current directory, and you will know how to write your file path

Comment: it should be "user.dir" as mentioned above by @khotyn