# Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, io

I am trying to read a file from the source folder, both the java file and text files are same location but program shows `FileNotFoundException`

Where should i put input file so program can find it?

[image]

Comment: Did you enter the exact location?

Comment: @ImAtWar i don't want to use absolute path, it's working with Absolute path, i want to use relative path

Comment: Shouldnt you declarate it as a file first? `File xanadu = new File("xanadu.txt");`

Comment: i want to use FileInputStream class only

Comment: The file class loads multiple parameters which are needed for the file input stream

Comment: but why is not working, what is wrong with this code, i don't want to go for alternate approach, i just want get rid of exception just to modify same class constructor. May be i am giving the wrong path for relative path, you know how to give relative path for this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100114/discussion-between-girdhar-singh-rathore-and-imatwar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have to use absolute path or put you text file in root folder. In your case put your txt file in `BasicIO`.

Comment: Thanks @anand mishra , its working under root folder

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
[FileInputStream("hello.txt"), doesn't work unless I specify an absolute path (C:\User\Documents etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406337/fileinputstreamhello-txt-doesnt-work-unless-i-specify-an-absolute-path-c)
Instantiate a File object with relative path ./name.txt e.g.:

```
File file = new File("./myfile.txt");
```

Make sure myfile.txt is in the root project folder.

Comment: Is your file in the project folder?

Comment: Thank you budy, its working when i put in root folder